# Java - Use search engine to return URL for search result?

Tags: java, url, search, jsoup

I currently have a Java program that returns a list of Football Team names to me in string format. These are scraped using jSoup.

I would now like to access that team's page on "futbol24.com" and scrape certain data from there. Unfortunately, my list of teams is in a different format to how futbol24 format their team names.

I would therefore like to do a search, for example "https://www.google.co.uk/#q=manchester+utd+futbol24" and return the first URL in the search results: "http://www.futbol24.com/team/England/Manchester-United/"

I have tried doing this in jSoup but with no successful results. Does anyone have an idea of how I could achieve this?

Thanks,

Rob

EDIT:

My current list of teams is formatted as such:

```
AS Saint Etienne
Lens
Schalke 04
Borussia M'gladbach
Deportivo La Coruna
Eibar
Central Coast Mariners
```

and I want to be able to pull each one out and run a search on "[TEAM] futbol24" for example, and then get the URL of the first search result.

Comment: I think this question is a bit unclear. Why not show how your list of teams is formatted.

Comment: I have now added some more clarity. Hope this helps? Thanks

Comment: I just had a look at the page source of the Google search result.  Good luck.  You might have an easier time using JSoup to parse the results of a different search engine.  For anyone else reading this, this type of screen scraping is very fragile and breaks easily when Google or futbol24 change their web site pages.